# python - enumerate next() not working

Tags: python, django

```
l = []
for i, obj in enumerate(queryset):
    if queryset[i].next():
        if queryset[i].common_id == queryset[i+1].common_id:
            l.append(queryset[i])
```

but I am getting:

```
'MyModel' object has no attribute 'next'
```

but [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) says:

> The next() method of the iterator returned by enumerate() returns a
>   tuple containing a count and the
>   values obtained from iterating over sequence

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe `queryset.next()` would work.

Comment: @TanveerAlam no, it doesnot, same error

Comment: As an aside: why not use `if obj.next()`?

Comment: @Evert it doesnot work, the same error

Comment: What kind of thing is `MyModel`: can you loop over that? This seems to be a Django model: you can't loop over a Django model isntance (it doesn't make sense).

Comment: I meant: if you're already doing `for i, obj in enumerate(queryset)`, use `obj` in the for loop, not `queryset[i]`. That's why it's an aside. Of course you get the same error: it's the same thing.

Comment: The `for` loop is implicitly calling `.next()` on the iterator returned by `enumerate()`.  You don't see the iterator anywhere inside your loop, you only see the return values of the `next()` method.

Comment: @Evert of course i can loop over them. i am using enumerate to get the next element in one loop step. i dont get what you say. ``why not use obj.next()`` and ``of course you get the same error, its the same thing?`` ??

Comment: @howaboutNO queryset is a set of queries results - meaning objects from database. thats why the tag ``django`` ;)

Comment: @doniyor you should mention that in your question. `;)`

Comment: You're attempting to call `next()` on a *single* queryset item (which is a model instance). Thus, you're trying to iterate over a single item, not the queryset. As fredtantini explains, the next call should operate on the queryset itself. (Then again, it probably should not, since you're already looping over it).

Comment: `queryset[i]` is the same thing as `obj` in your for-loop. That's how `enumerate` works. Print the `id()`s, and you'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `next()` method you are talking about is for the iterator returned by `enumerate`. For instance:

```
>>> someIterator = enumerate(range(5,10))
>>> tuple = someIterator.next()
>>> tuple
(0, 5)
```

When doing a for loop, the for loop calls `enumerate(...).next()` each step. It's like when you are doing in C `for (i=0;i<10;i++)`, in the core of the loop, you don't have to increment `i` anymore.

If in your loop you just need to access some object and the next, you should take care of the last step:

```
>>> l = range(5,10)
>>> for i, obj in enumerate(l):
...   print l[i],l[i+1]
...
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9
9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

and instead only use range:

```
>>> for i in range(len(l)-1):
...   print l[i],l[i+1]
...
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9
```

since in your loop, you don't use `obj` anyway.
You can also take special care of the last step:

```
>>> l = range(5,10)
>>> for i, obj in enumerate(l):
...   if i<len(l)-1:
...     print l[i],l[i+1]
...   else:
...     print l[i]
...
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9
9
```

Or use the iterator in a while loop (when there is no item, `next()` raises a StopIteration

```
>>> someIterator = enumerate("abcde")
>>> current = someIterator.next()
>>> try:
...     while someIterator:
...        nextOne = someIterator.next()
...        print current, nextOne
...        if current == nextOne:
...           pass#dosomething
...        current = nextOne
... except:
...     print "end of iteration", current
...
(0, 'a') (1, 'b')
(1, 'b') (2, 'c')
(2, 'c') (3, 'd')
(3, 'd') (4, 'e')
end of iteration (4, 'e')
```

Comment: how can I access the element of next loop?

Comment: exactly the 2nd example is what I want, but i need to know ``list index out of range`` beforehand. this is what I am trying to achieve. if I do ``if l[i+1]:`` it is still giving index error. I cannot use the 3rd example because I need the last element also

Comment: But you will compare l[i+1] to what?

Comment: i compare l[i] to l[i+1] only if l[i+1] exists, otherwise, i will take l[i] itself. i cannot check that ``only if l[i+1] exists`` part right now.. i am getting index error

Comment: got your last edit, nice! thank you! huge hugs from me!

Comment: then you have to specially take care of that case (see my last exemple with the for loop) or use a try/catch

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a better way to handle this is to use `zip` in a list comprehension:

```
l = [item for item, next_item in zip(queryset, queryset[1:])
         if item.common_id == next_item.common_id]
```